# laravel-10 AWS SQS queue listen giving 403 forbidden in ECS container

Tags: amazon-sqs, laravel-queue, httpforbiddenhandler

Getting below error when I am running

```
php artisan listen:queue --queue=dev-rc-lead-create.fifo
```

> [2023-06-28 10:20:53] dev.ERROR: Error executing "ReceiveMessage" on
> "https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/7xxxxxxxxx7/dev-rc-lead-create.fifo";
> AWS HTTP error: Client error: `POST https://sqs.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/7xxxxxxxxx7/dev-rc-lead-create.fifo`
> resulted in a `403 Forbidden` response: Sender`I
> (truncated...)  InvalidClientTokenId (client): The security token
> included in the request is invalid. - SenderInvalidClientTokenId`The
> security token included in the request is
> invalid.34f80cf6-7720-5062-97b2-51e07b5853f2

I am expecting job to listen published messages from queue